# Rate of convergence involving bivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Suppose $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are bivariate normal, marginally standardized, and has correlation $\rho$. Fix $z_0>0$.

I am interested in finding an estimate of the rate of convergence the probability $P(Z_1<z_0, Z_2>z_0)$ to $0$ as $\rho\uparrow 1$. Is such type of result known?

Comment: Please, could you share your work on the subject?